# What is the theoretical maximum score in Junkenstein's Revenge 2017?

Tags: overwatch

Right now the current highest score in Junkenstein's Revenge (classic, non endless) is 32,676 points by a team in the Asia region. This is over 3000 points higher than the top scores from last year.

How is it possible to get such a high score, and what is the maximum possible score?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To achieve a high score, you must play on Legendary difficulty.

### Point Sources

#### Boss Completion (6800 pts)

Every boss that you clear as you go through a run gives you points, regardless of speed:

- Reaper grants 400 points
- Junkenstein, Junkenstein's Monster, The Summoner, and The Witch grant 800 points

There are 3 reapers in the full run, 1 Witch, and 2 of each of the other three bosses. This gives us `400 * 3  + 800 * 7 = 6800 points`.

#### Door Health Bonus (6000 pts)

[image: Door Health Bonus Sample Screenshot]

The door bonus displayed at the end of the game is DOUBLED when it is applied to your score. You can achieve a maximum of 3000 door bonus (no damage to door), which is doubled to 6000 points in Legendary mode.

- One basic zomnic removes 180 points from the door bonus (pre-doubling).
- One shock tire removes ??? points from the door bonus (pre-doubling).

#### Elite Elimination Bonuses (3600 pts)

[image: Elite Elimination Bonus Sample Screenshot]

If you take down the boss enemies quickly, you will receive an *Elite Elimination* bonus. Each boss has a maximum Elite Bonus of 100 or 250. These bonuses are doubled when applied to your score.

- Reaper can grant a maximum of 100pts
- Junkenstein, Junkenstein's Monster, and The Summoner can each grant a maximum of 250pts
- The Witch offers no Elite Elimination Bonus.

3 reapers and 2 of each other scoring boss: `2 * ((3 * 100) + (6 * 250)) = 3600 points` maximum.

NOTE: The timing window of the bonus gets smaller for each consecutive spawn of the boss. For example, killing the first Reaper in 7 seconds will net the full 100 elite bonus. However, killing the third reaper in 7 seconds will net less than 50 points. This applies to all subsequent spawns of the same boss monster.

#### Basic Enemy Kills (6000+ pts)

Killing a Zomnic, Zombardier, or Shock Tire grants a small amount of points during the main stage of the game. Basic enemies killed after the timer reaches 0:00 are with 0 points.

- Zomnics and Zombardiers are worth 20 points each.
- Shock Tires are worth 80 points each.

There are 10 shock tires that spawn during the main event, but the number of Zomnics that spawn in a game is variable. But in a full run you can expect to get at least 6000 points from zomnics and shock tires.

How can you maximize the number of zomnics that spawn? There may be an RNG component, but it appears that killing zomnics quickly results in new spawns appearing quickly. In some runs, you may be able to get 7000 or more points from basic enemies. More on this in the Survival Bonus section.

#### Survival Bonus (7200+ pts)

[image: Incremental Survival Bonus Screenshot]

Survival Bonus is granted in monotonically increasing increments throughout the main stage of the event (before 0:00) as long as no players die. This bonus is also doubled from what is shown on the screen when it is applied to your score.

- Survival bonus is granted approximately every 25 zomnics killed (500 points worth of zomnics)
- The first survival bonus granted is worth 25 points
- Each subsequent survival bonus granted is worth an additional 50 points

  - 75, 125, 175, 225, ...
  - Up to a maximum of 575 points (12th and final wave)
  - Note: 12 waves of 500 zomnic points = 6000 points of zomnics.
- After receiving the 12th survival bonus, you will not receive more survival bonus unless a player dies.
- If a player dies at any time, the survival bonus counter is reset. The next survival bonus will grant 25 points.

Adding up the survival bonuses from the 12 waves and multiplying by 2 gives us 7200 points. However, if you read between the lines in the last two sections, it may be possible to make use of Intentional Deaths to increase the maximum Survival bonus.

In some runs, players achieve the 575 Survival Bonus [with almost 1 minute remaining on the clock](https://youtu.be/xm0qWqqCUaY?t=452). If you took an intentional death at this point, and continued killing Zomnics you could conceivably achieve the first two survival bonuses again for an extra 400 points (`(25 + 75)*2)`).

### Summary & Strategy

If we start adding up these numbers, it is easy to see how a 30000 point score is possible now.

- 6800 for Boss completion.

  - *Finish the game*
- 6000 for Door Health Bonus.

  - *Don't take door damage*
- 7200 for 12 waves of Survival bonus.

  - *Survive and kill 300 zomnics*
- 6000 points of Zomnic kills.

  - *Kill 300 zomnics*.

This alone would get us to 26000 points. You might consider this the "base" score of a good Junkenstein's run. On top of this there can be

- 3600 max Elite bonus.

  - Killing each boss quickly the first time around already nets 1700 points
  - *Kill bosses quickly*
- 1000 extra zomnic points if zomnics spawn quickly enough.

  - *Kill Zomnics quickly*.
- 200 extra survivor bonus with intentional deaths.

  - *Die after achieving the 575 survival bonus, and kill more zomnics quickly*

Giving us a theoretical total score of.... 30,800. It's still not enough!

### Scoring Extrapolation

Based on the information so far, only kills and Survival Bonus can scale indefinitely. Let's assume a perfect score for every other bonus.

`6000 DB + 6800 BC + 3600 EB = 16400 score`

On top of this, assuming 25 zomnic kills per level of Survival Bonus, here's how the scores scale:

```
+-------+-------+---------------+--------------------+
| Kills | Bonus | Running Total | Perfect Game Total |
+-------+-------+---------------+--------------------+
|     0 |     0 |             0 |              16400 |
|    25 |    25 |           550 |              16950 |
|   ... |   ... |           ... |                ... |
|   275 |   525 |         11550 |              27950 |
|   300 |   575 |         13200 |              29600 |
|   325 |    25 |         13750 |              30150 |
|   350 |    75 |         14400 |              30800 |
|   375 |   125 |         15150 |              31550 |
|   400 |   175 |         16000 |              32400 |
|   425 |   225 |         16950 |              33350 |
|   450 |   275 |         18000 |              34400 |
|   475 |   325 |         19150 |              35550 |
|   ... |   ... |           ... |                ... |
|   575 |   525 |         24750 |              41150 |
|   600 |   575 |         26400 |              42800 |
+-------+-------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Here, if we assume a perfect score on all other aspects, **we can infer that the 32,676 score had between 400 and 425 zomnic kills**. If there were not perfect elite elimination scores (quite possible), this could have been as much as 450 zomnic eliminations: 1.5x the amount required to get the full standard survival bonus.

You can see in the table how the scores would scale up rapidly from that point.

In my experience, the earliest I've reached max survival bonus is around the first Junkenstein's fight (1:45 on the clock). This is about 75% of the way through the main event. To achieve the highest score, you may have to achieve the max survival bonus by just after the symmetra fight (2:30~),

Comment: Could use info on shock tire damage, exact timing info for boss bonuses, formatting/editing, and any other scoring exploits available.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking up a way to achieve a higher score just last night and stumbled upon this. A group I was with was trying to figure out what you can do to maximize the score and were convinced that it was somehow tied to end bonuses that were only added in for perfect performances... no door damage... no deaths... whatever...

The problem is no deaths appeared to not be scaling the points up as much as we thought, and the answer above talking about survival bonus is the only thing that makes sense in why this was happening.

If the survival bonus is capped after 300 kills, until you restart it again by dieing than it makes sense how runs where you made it to the final mercy spawn without dieing were already maxed out.

If survival bonus was capped by that point, even if you don't have any deaths on the final elite spawn it doesn't change much.

I also believe Sims answer is correct when saying it's extremely difficult to get all the fast elite kill bonuses, and I agree with this especially on legendary mode.

This leaves me to believe that they are correct that exploiting 1 intentional death at 300 kills is actually the only way to achieve a higher score past all the other bonuses.  I really don't like this gimmick, because it's counter intuitive to just flat out playing well.